# What are the different endings in Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Needless to say, the answers to this question will be full of spoilers.

What are the 16 possible endings in *The Witcher 2*?

Comment: I've submitted the spoiler tag as an edit - you should add that to questions like these so that people who have added the tag to their ignore list won't see it.

Comment: @Alex The spoiler tag is intended to be used only when there are spoilers in the title; do you think that the game having 16 endings is a spoiler?

Comment: @Mana Not particularly, possibly a minor spoiler. I was under the impression the tag was for the entire question, not just the title. I've now seen the tag description and it is as you say, but considering you can see the first few sentences of the post in the Questions list I don't see why this is only applied to the title. The first few words could easily be a spoiler. Might bring this up in meta, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @Alex But the first few words *aren't* a spoiler. Unless, again, the fact there are 16 endings is a particularly nasty spoiler. But if that is the case, no reason we can't just amend it to say "All of the possible endings" instead, neh?

Comment: @Grace Note - Not in this case, no. I agree that here the spoiler tag was not appropriate, as its usage is currently defined (title only). What I meant was, say I ask a question whose title contains no spoiler, but the first few words _are_ a spoiler. According to the current usage, I shouldn't tag it as a spoiler, but I don't think that makes sense - there _is_ a spoiler and it's clearly visible, it's just not in the title.

Comment: @Alex There's been a couple proposals regarding how to counter that. My personal thought pattern has always been, "Don't put the spoiler material right at the front, if it can be avoided". There's been a few Meta discussions, both here and in our base at Meta Stack Overflow, though, so perhaps something can be worked out.

Comment: Mmm, would the new title be better?

Comment: @Extrakun hehe the title is fine :) In response to your actual question, I can't find any list of all the different combinations, but there's a clarification from the developers about what "16 endings" actually means: http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2010-11-30-16-witcher-2-endings-claim-clarified

Comment: it's unfortunate that the game isn't as good as the first one , what drew most people to the first one is the complexity of the story and the various missions it had , different types of characters , all of that is missing in the Witcher 2 , i believe the game is nothing but a commercial release a way for the company to make more $ without worrying about the quality

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Witcher_2_Ending not so clear answer to the question and still needs some editing.

**Roche's PathEdit**

-If you decided to kill King Henselt then the meeting in Chapter 3 will change a lot.

-If you let him live, Henselt doesn't only have Upper Aedirn but whole of Aedirn will be given to him as there isn't anyone left to ascend to the Aederninan throne because prince Stennis dies in the ghostly mist.

*If you went with Vernon Roche to save King Foltest's daughter, Anais, and you convince Roche to give the Anais to Temeria. Then Roche wil say that she decided to pick up a sword instead of a doll, and will be a great leader.

*If you went with Roche to save King Foltest's daughter, and you convince Roche to give the daughter to Radovid. She will grow up to marry Radovid and Redania will protect Temeria for the time.

_In the Epilogue, If you went to save Triss yourself, then on your the path to see Letho, You will see Roche saved Anais by himself and is defending her from a bunch of soldiers. You will save him.

**Iorveth's Path**

-If you decide to save Philippa Eilhart, then you will be able to release dragon from her control. You will not be given an option to kill her.

-If you decide to save Triss instead, then you will be given an option of killing the dragon or leaving it. Iorveth would've went to save Philippa and then get badly hurt by her. You will be given the option to walk away and leave Iorveth to the troops, or attack them and tell Triss to save her. She will say that he is badly hurt and will take months to heal him.

**Shared Choices**

If you saved Sheala de Tancarville, Letho will mention she will be hunted by Royal witch-hunters and die a slow death by them. If you let her die, then Letho will say you showed her mercy.

In both paths, if you save Triss instead, the Council of Sorcerers will still be created, since Triss is the one that pointed out Sile was the traitor.

If you did not save Triss, she will be saved by Lethos, Shilard Fitz-Oesterlen will point out Sile as the traitor and the Council of Sorcerers will not be created, as people will be hunting witches from then on.

**Ending Sequence**

If you go with Roche/Iorveth in Chapter 3, then you will walk out with Roche/Iorveth and Triss.

If you go with Triss, you will walk out with Triss only.

**Ending Plot Summary**

No matter what, Nilfgaard will be on the march north to invade the northern kingdoms. Lethos was employed by Nilfgaard to kill Kings in the northern kingdom to soften them up for the later invasion. Letho used the Lodge of Sorceresses as a cover to kill the Kings because they initally had the same objective.

Lodge of Sorceresses initally only?? wanted to kill Demavend because he was shown to be a weak King. But after his death, Letho used Sorceresses' resources to get in contact with Scoia'tael to kill King Foltest and King Henselt. After the death of Foltest, Letho split with Iorveth and went into hiding, Letho couldn't trust Iorveth anymore as Iorveth and the Sorcereses figured out Letho's true plan.

Answer (score 2):

If you think of it, there is actually only one ending. Southern Empire attacks weakened northern kingdoms and it's no more your business. You either farewell Roche/Iorveth or leave with them but it doesn't matter, Roche saves little princess anyway and Iorveth never gets his elven dream come true. You eitherway end up with Triss, nevermind who saved her and you live happily ever after... until "The Witcher 3" (which I hope will be made soon).